# convert string value to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to pass csv data as argument in postman.

Which can be like

```
s = 2,3,4,5
s= "2,3,4,5"
```

This csv data is coming from some csv file. I can directly pas it like

```
localhost?data="2,3,4,5"
```

How to parse it correctly and convert it into numpy array?

I tried this

```
s = "2,3,4,5"
print(np.array(list(s)))
```

Which gives

```
['1' ',' '2' ',' '3' ',' '4']
```

which is wrong.

```
d =np.fromstring(s[1:-1],sep=' ').astype(int)
```

Gives `array([], dtype=int64)` which I dont understand.

What is the correct way?

Comment: `print(np.array(s.split(",")).astype(int))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split on comma and then use `np.array`

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np

s = "2,3,4,5"
print(np.array(s.strip('"').split(",")).astype(int))
```

**Output:**

```
[2 3 4 5]
```

Comment: Thanks bit it gives me `data = np.array(data.split(",")).astype(int)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"1'`

Comment: use `.strip('"')`

Answer (score 4):

You could try [`np.fromstring()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) as in

```
import numpy as np
s = "2,3,4,5"
np.fromstring(s, dtype=int, sep=',')
```

to get output like

```
array([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s='2,3,4,5'
>>> np.array([int(i) for i in s.split(',')])
array([2, 3, 4, 5])
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives me `data = np.array([int(i) for i in data.split(',')])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"1'`

Comment: What data have you used to test it? As you can see in the example above, for the string ```'2,3,4,5'``` it is working fine.